# Texture displays only on one side

Tags: materials

When in rendered mode Blender displays material only on upper side of the object. How can I fix that?

[image: Upper side]

[image: Lower side]

[image: Material (Leaves)]

[image: Environment]

[image: UV]

Comment: yes, not normal, can you share your file?

Comment: https://we.tl/XD7s9bKL3m

Comment: Your texture is on both sides, it's just your World background that makes a very intense light and burns your texture, if you add a lamp and delete your World you can see it normally (don't know what is this World setting though)

Comment: Are you sure because I've added a sun lamp now and I still get the same result? (without the World setting)

Comment: I can see now that if I rotate the sun underneath I get the opposite effect (upper side gets white)

Comment: the problem is your World but I don't know why, I don't use World often

Comment: I understand, actually you also have a lot of transparency on your leaves, so, as the sky is intense, you see through them

Comment: Yes but I deleted the World scene and it is still the same. I've also tried in a new .blend file.

Comment: because of your material: too many transparent/translucent, it makes your leaves look white if you look through the opposite of light, play with the nodes, or rotate your leaves 180° and you'll see

Answer (score 1):

Your texture is on both sides of your leaves, actually you have two other problems:

- Your leaves have a lot of transparency/translucency, so what you see when you look form underneath is the sky through your leaves
- The sky of your Background is a little bit too strong so it enlightens a bit too much your leaves